# WPF WebBrowser in TabItem not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

I'm using WPF and need to populate a dynamically generated TabControl with a number of tabs.

I'm having trouble with the WebBrowser element, which seems to successfully navigate (I can see the mouse changes cursor as I hover through different elements) but the browser only displays white.

My code is below:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
TabItem aTabItem = new TabItem() { Header = "My Tab", Width = 180, FontSize = 16, Content = (browser as WebBrowser) };

(Form.FindName("MyTabControl") as TabControl).Items.Add(aTabItem);
(Form.FindName("MyTabControl") as TabControl).SelectedItem = aTabItem;

browser.NavigateToString("http://www.google.com");
```

So basically I create the TabItem, add the WebBrowser to it, add the TabItem to the TabControl which will hold all tabs created.

When I try this the WebBrowser isn't displayed. If I swap it for a Label with some text, the Label will happily show up.

Could you give me some pointers?
Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back, not identical but I found some helper somewhere saying that calling `browser.Navigate("about:blank");` first then doing you main navigation helped.

Comment: Worth a quick try if you can. Let me know what happens

Comment: Tried your approach, seemed plausible because WebBrowser seems to be an ActiveX element, and not native to WPF, so may have needed a kick to work properly. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm even more confused now because I tried a very similar approach at home and worked nicely, I had to give the browser a `width` and `height` for it to display, but trying that at work still didn't display the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately not got the time to do any exploration although I will look later. If this isn't working at your work environment but is at your home, could it be something as simple as a firewall blocking access to your application?

Comment: I found the issue, I had the browser in a window that allowed transparency.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. The window where I had the WebBrowser was set as `AllowsTransparency="true"`. I should have known better...

Comment: sometimes it's the simplest things!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        TabItem TI = new TabItem() { Header = "My Tab", Width = 180, FontSize = 16, Content = (browser as WebBrowser) };
        tabcontrol.Items.Add(TI);            
        browser.Source= new Uri("http://www.google.com");
```

I have used the `Source` of `WebBrowser` control. and i am creating the `Uri`.

**`NavigateToString(string text)`** works like below from `MSDN`

```
If the text parameter is null, WebBrowser navigates to a blank document ("about:blank").
If the text parameter is not in valid HTML format, it will be displayed as plain text.
After navigation, Source will be null.
```

Comment: I have tried the source but still doesn't display the browser. I noticed on a separate project that the browser needs a `width` and `height` but on my main project that still doesn't help displaying the browser.